# Servicestack reverse routing exception

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to get the absolute url out of a ServicesSatck service but I'm receiving the following exception:

> None of the given rest routes matches 'SingleUser' request:
>     /user/UserName/{UserName}:  Allowed HTTP methods 'Get' does not
>   support the specified 'GET' method.

SingleUser class has the following routes declared as metadata :

```
   [Route("/user", "Get")]
   [Route("/user/{Id}", "Get")]
   [Route("/user/UserName/{UserName}", "Get")]
```

The exception apepars when I try to call

```
   var url = new SingleUser { UserName = userSession.UserName}.ToAbsoluteUri();
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually the problem was with the capitalization of the HTTP method on the route declaration. 
It worked after I set the route as follows

```
[Route("/user/UserName/{UserName}", "GET")]
```

The service has been working, even when it was declared as "Get" but the "ToAbsoluteUri()" brought up the problem.